# Where can I find the python Zeitgeist Programming modules?

Tags: python, zeitgeist

On the Zeitgeist [launchpad page](https://launchpad.net/zeitgeist), a [link to a python API tutorial](http://bloc.eurion.net/archives/2012/zeitgeist-python-api-tutorial/) has been given for beginners.

I've fully configured and installed the zeitgeist-1.0 tarball from the launchpad site, but I still can't find or use the zeitgeist modules while python programming.
 Please Help.
edit:
I haven't tried anything yet, i've just installed the whole package. I've also got the following packages installed. libzeitgeist-1.0-1:amd64 libzeitgeist-2.0-0:amd64 python-zeitgeist rhythmbox-plugin-zeitgeist zeitgeist zeitgeist-core zeitgeist-datahub zeitgeist-explorer.

Also I am working in python 3.5 on ipython3.

Comment: Your question is not clear. What did you try to "find or use" them? If you've installed a module, you should be able to import it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to install **python-zeitgeist** module:

```
pip install --user python-zeitgeist
```

or

```
sudo apt-get install python-zeitgeist
```

Looking for example code, take a look [here](http://bloc.eurion.net/archives/2012/zeitgeist-python-api-tutorial/)

```
from zeitgeist.client import ZeitgeistClient
from zeitgeist.datamodel import *

zeitgeist = ZeitgeistClient()

def on_events_received(events):
    if events:
        song = events[0]
        print "Last song: %s" % song.subjects[0].uri
    else:
        print "You haven't listened to any songs."

template = Event.new_for_values(subject_interpretation=Interpretation.AUDIO)
zeitgeist.find_events_for_template(template, on_events_received, num_events=1)

# Start a mainloop - note: the Qt mainloop also works
from gi.repository import GLib
GLib.MainLoop().run()
```

Comment: Thanks for answering.
I've already got python-zeitgeist installed, how should I proceed?

Comment: So, I just update the answer to add a code example and a link to code example.